# How do I change a button label created with 'interact_manual' from 'ipywidgets'? and how do I change the size and color of that button?

Tags: python, button, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How do I change a button label created with 'interact_manual' from 'ipywidgets'? and how do I change the size and colour of that button?

Here is what I wrote

```
from ipywidgets import interact,interact_manual
def HDI_vs_CrimeRate():
    #do some thing here
interact_manual(HDI_vs_CrimeRate)
```

and here is how the button looks like:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClLVi.png)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may need to upgrade your ipywidgets; for me, your code returns a button with the label 'Run Interact', which is a little better than yours but not yet what you want.

Assign your interact_manual to a variable, alter the description text of the child widget, and then call display() on your interact. This seems to get the job done, although there may be a more elegant way.

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual
def HDI_vs_CrimeRate():
    #do some thing here
im = interact_manual(HDI_vs_CrimeRate)
im.widget.children[0].description = 'changed'
display(im)
```

Edit: For color, you can use im.widget.children[0].style.button_color = 'red'.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you accept the answer by clicking the tick if it solves your problem?

Comment: BTW, I could not change the button colour. Also when I use a label which is long, the button size won't adjust the size to fit the label. Do you also have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Which version of ipywidgets are you using? Using `im.widget.children[0].style.button_color = 'red'` works for me on 7.2.1. Do you receive any error msg?

Comment: Note here that `im.widget.children[0]`, 0 corresponds to the number of parameters `HDI_vs_CrimeRate` takes. If it had 2 parameters, you need to put 2.

Answer (score 6):

The preferred way (as of March 2021) for changing the button text is probably via `options`:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact_manual
def HDI_vs_CrimeRate():
    return ...  # Do something here
my_interact_manual = interact_manual.options(manual_name="changed")
my_interact_manual(HDI_vs_CrimeRate);
```

The documentation is a bit scarce in this regard, it is only mentioned in the [ipywidgets changelog](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html?highlight=manual_name) for version 7.2.

Comment: Previous answer did not work for me (no change) and this did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

by using decorator:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual
x=widgets.interact_manual.options(manual_name="changed")
@x
def HDI_vs_CrimeRate():
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If using `ipywidgets.interactive`, to change from "Run Interact" to something else:

```
import datetime as dt
doit = lambda: print(dt.datetime.now())
w = widgets.interactive(doit, {'manual': True, "manual_name": "Refresh"})
display(w)
```