# Rename checkboxes of ipywidgets.interact

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How to rename displayed checkboxes of ipywidgets.interact to be different from names of variables?

```
import ipywidgets
def print_var(_print_or_not):
    if _print_or_not:
        print("printed")
    else:
        print("don't print")

ipywidgets.interact_manual(print_var, _print_or_not=True)
```

I want to have a custom text as the label of the checkbox.
[image]

Edit: I don't want to change the label of the interact button, but the label of the checkbox ("_print_or_not" in this case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change a button label created with 'interact\_manual' from 'ipywidgets'? and how do I change the size and color of that button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346765/how-do-i-change-a-button-label-created-with-interact-manual-from-ipywidgets)

Comment: @PeteKirkham No, my question is about the checkboxes, not the interact button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be closed as duplicate of [How do I change a button label created with 'interact_manual' from 'ipywidgets'? and how do I change the size and color of that button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346765/how-do-i-change-a-button-label-created-with-interact-manual-from-ipywidgets)

Applying the solution from that question renames the checkbox as below:

[image: Output using linked solution]