# Jupyter Widgets Formatting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am using the following code:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(x):
    return x

interact_manual(f, x='Hi there!');
```

It yields the following widget in the notebook:

[image]

[image]

The issue is that the text box has a fixed default size that is very small, I would like to increase the size of the text box so that the user's text does not get cutoff. I would also like to change the text shown on the button from the default "Run Interact" to something custom.

I have extensively gone over the documentation and looked online and I cannot find a single example of code that shows how you can set any kind of formatting for the interact/interact_manual function.

Is there any way to change the size of the text box and format other attributes of the widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Basics: pass in widget to specify options

The essential point is that you can pass a specific widgets into the interactive, interact, and interact_manual calls. Then because of that you can control the text box width like I do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77848199/8508004).

Here is an example for `interact()`:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="Enter text here:",
        style={"description_width": "initial"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'), 
    )

def f(x):
    return x

interact(f, x=text_input);
```

That works with `interact_manual()`, too:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="Enter text here:",
        style={"description_width": "initial"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'), 
    )

def f(x):
    return x

interact_manual(f, x=text_input);
```

This is covered under [the 'Using Interact' page](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) where there are a lot of illustrative examples. A couple particularly pertinent to the OP are presently found under 'interact_manual' where it has an example for `interact_manual()` of: `interact_manual(slow_function,i=FloatSlider(min=1e5, max=1e7, step=1e5));`. And then it has an example of `interactive()` that is similar, yet distinct, below it & that one shows passing in the specific widget: `slow = interactive(slow_function, {'manual': True}, i=widgets.FloatSlider(min=1e4, max=1e6, step=1e4))`.

---

##### Addressing customizing "Run Interact" text on the `interact_manual()` button

OP also said:

> 'I would also like to change the text shown on the button from the default "Run Interact" to something custom.'

For that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66639048/8508004) first assigns custom `manual_name` to the options for an instance of `interact_manual()` and then uses that to build in the other widgets.

Here is that approach combined in to the last code block example above:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="Enter text here:",
        style={"description_width": "initial"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'), 
    )

def f(x):
    return x

my_customized_interact_manual = interact_manual.options(manual_name="Click here to proceed")
my_customized_interact_manual(f, x=text_input);
```

---

##### Addendum: How to pass in multiple widgets

This question was asked in reply in the comments:

> "...what happens if my function has another argument that is a Boolean that generate a toggle box, how would I set the formatting for the toggle box?"

You would chain together passing in additional widgets with the settings you want, accomodating those in the function and referencing them in the `interact()` invocation.

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="Enter text here:",
        style={"description_width": "initial"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'), 
    )
checkbox_input = widgets.Checkbox(
        value=True, 
        description='Toggle True/False', 
        disabled=False, 
        indent=False)
# Checkbox options adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/q/75434840/8508004

def f(x, y):
    return x, y

interact(f, x=text_input, y=checkbox_input);
```

[The top of this related complex example I wrote in reply to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75868977/8508004) might help further illustrate this as well.

Comment: Seconding that. And bravo on the clear answer, was able to replicate.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for the answer, but what happens if my function has another argument that is a Boolean that generate a toggle box, how would I set the formatting for the toggle box? where did you find the docs/guide to figure out how to format the text box?

Comment: "where did you find the docs/guide to figure out how to format the text box?" It is in there. [The 'Using Interact' page](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) has a lot of illustrative examples. A couple particularly pertinent to this question you have is presently found under 'interact_manual' where it has an example for `interact_manual()` of: `interact_manual(slow_function,i=FloatSlider(min=1e5, max=1e7, step=1e5));`. And then it has an example of `interactive()` that is similar, yet distinct, below it & that one shows passing in the specific widget.

Comment: I added an 'Addendum' at the end covering your question, "what happens if my function has another argument that is a Boolean that generate a toggle box, how would I set the formatting for the toggle box?" I've also added back in a code example about how to change the 'Run Interact' label on the button made by `interact_manual()`.